# Arduino builds fail with "Reset.h: No such file or directory"

Tags: arduino

When I'm trying to build what seems to be any code in the Arduino IDE, it fails with this error:

`Arduino: 1.6.5 (Mac OS X), Board: "Arduino Mega or Mega 2560, ATmega2560 (Mega 2560)"`

/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/USBCore.cpp:19:19: fatal error: Reset.h: No such file or directory
 #include "Reset.h"
                   ^
compilation terminated.
Error compiling.

This report would have more information with
  "Show verbose output during compilation"
  enabled in File > Preferences.

The code I'm trying to build is from https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Fade:

```
/*
 Fade

 This example shows how to fade an LED on pin 9
 using the analogWrite() function.

 The analogWrite() function uses PWM, so if
 you want to change the pin you're using, be
 sure to use another PWM capable pin. On most
 Arduino, the PWM pins are identified with
 a "~" sign, like ~3, ~5, ~6, ~9, ~10 and ~11.

 This example code is in the public domain.
 */

int led = 9;           // the PWM pin the LED is attached to
int brightness = 0;    // how bright the LED is
int fadeAmount = 5;    // how many points to fade the LED by

// the setup routine runs once when you press reset:
void setup() {
  // declare pin 9 to be an output:
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
}

// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {
  // set the brightness of pin 9:
  analogWrite(led, brightness);

  // change the brightness for next time through the loop:
  brightness = brightness + fadeAmount;

  // reverse the direction of the fading at the ends of the fade:
  if (brightness == 0 || brightness == 255) {
    fadeAmount = -fadeAmount ;
  }
  // wait for 30 milliseconds to see the dimming effect
  delay(30);
}
```

Why is this happening?  I don't think I've changed any of the Arduino libraries, but wondering if that's the case now.  A find in /Applications/Arduino.app/ lists no files called Reset.h, however, I did find a ~/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/sam/1.6.4/cores/arduino/Reset.h.

Building with Arduino IDE 1.6.5, using a Mega 2560 and /dev/cu.usbmodem1421.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my Android installation was modified, and the modified USBCore.cpp wasn't really correct for this version (1.6.5) of Arduino.  Reinstalling fixed the problem.